# Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element is missing

Tags: java

hello i have this problem with my java server wen user connect give this..

how to fix this problem? server are linux centos 7

server have 2 gb ram and 2 core 2500mhz

---

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element is missing.
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.Parser2.fatal(Parser2.java:3182)
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.Parser2.fatal(Parser2.java:3170)
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.Parser2.parseInternal(Parser2.java:501)
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.Parser2.parse(Parser2.java:305)
    at org.apache.crimson.parser.XMLReaderImpl.parse(XMLReaderImpl.java:442)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:453)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:770)
    at jQ.a(Unknown Source)
    at bp.a(Unknown Source)
    at kw.decode(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:67)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:792)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:352)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:334)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:207)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:94)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:372)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:246)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:38)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.execution.MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor$MemoryAwareRunnable.run(MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.java:613)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Put some code, is it related to xml parsing code?

Comment: It seems the incoming xml does not have a root element. Which xml? We don't know...

Comment: Show us your xml document please, does it have a proper root element?

Comment: We have seen some strage characters in the first line of the xml and we used to get this kind of exception. Please check the XML

Comment: *Strange characters* is a good keyword given by @HariPrasad, please check the file encoding.